# C++ : How does Virtual Function resolve "this" pointer scope issue?

Tags: c++, virtual-functions, mingw32

(C++,MinGW 4.4.0,Windows OS)

All that is commented in the code, except labels <1> and <2>, is my guess. Please correct me in case you think I'm wrong somewhere:

```
class A {
public:
   virtual void disp(); //not necessary to define as placeholder in vtable entry will be
                        //overwritten when derived class's vtable entry is prepared after
                        //invoking Base ctor (unless we do new A instead of new B in main() below)
};

class B :public A {
public:
   B() : x(100) {}
   void disp() {std::printf("%d",x);}
   int x;
};

int main() {
   A* aptr=new B;             //memory model and vtable of B (say vtbl_B) is assigned to aptr
   aptr->disp();              //<1> no error
   std::printf("%d",aptr->x); //<2> error -> A knows nothing about x
}
```

<2> is an error and is obvious. Why <1> is not an error? What I think is happening for this invocation is: `aptr->disp(); --> (*aptr->*(vtbl_B + offset to disp))(aptr)` `aptr` in the parameter being the implicit `this` pointer to the member function. Inside `disp()` we would have `std::printf("%d",x); --> std::printf("%d",aptr->x); SAME AS std::printf("%d",this->x);` So why does <1> give no error while <2> does?

(I know vtables are implementation specific and stuff but I still think it's worth asking the question)

Answer (score 4):

`this` is not the same as `aptr` inside `B::disp`. The `B::disp` implementation takes `this` as `B*`, just like any other method of `B`. When you invoke virtual method via `A*` pointer, it is converted to `B*` first (which may even change its value so it is not necessarily equal to `aptr` during the call).

I.e. what really happens is something like

```
typedef void (A::*disp_fn_t)();
disp_fn_t methodPtr = aptr->vtable[index_of_disp]; // methodPtr == &B::disp

B* b = static_cast<B*>(aptr);
(b->*methodPtr)(); // same as b->disp()
```

For more complicated example, check this post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/02/06/68695.aspx. Here, if there are multiple `A` bases which may invoke the same `B::disp`, MSVC generates different entry points with each one shifting `A*` pointer by different offset. This is implementation-specific, of course; other compilers may choose to store the offset somewhere in vtable for example.

Comment: this answer exactly clears the doubt for me (conversion of A* to B*, without which i still fail to see, due lack of knowledge on my part maybe,  how can `this->x` resolve correctly inside `void B::disp(B* const this) {}` when passing A* as `this`)..but what is don't understand is compiler does not know at compile time if `methodPtr==&B::disp` or `methodPtr==&A::disp`..we can have `void f(A* aptr) {aptr->disp();}` and `if(something) f(&bObj); else f(&aObj);` for the latter there is no point of staic_casting as you showed. (i have a feeling i'm screwing up :) )....

Comment: further memory model of A and B coincide and things seem easier to explain here. What if A were a second Base class to B. The pointer alignment would break but B::disp() could still access non-private members of the leftmost Base class. I think `this` statically resolves to finding out/pointing to member variables when `new B` is encountered and `this->aMemberVar` is not touched upon at runtime any further.

Comment: @ustulation Check my updated answer. For example, MSVC generates “trampolines” for every possible way of invoking `B::disp` through pointer to base, each casting `this` appropriately and then jumping to `B::disp` itself.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is:

> ***In C++ dynamic dispatch only works for member functions functions not for member variables.***

For a member variable the compiler only looksup for the symbol name in that particular class or its base classes.

In case 1, the appropriate method to be called is decided by *fetching* the `vpt`, *fetching* the address of the appropriate method and then *calling* the appropiate member function.
Thus dynamic dispatch is essentially a `fetch-fetch-call` instead of a normal `call` in case of static binding.

In Case 2: The compiler only looks for `x` in the scope of `this` Obviously, it cannot find it and reports the error.

Comment: ok but `this` is sliced to know about only `A` for <1>. Inside the member function i think the calls resolve to `this->whatEver`. What is confusing me is since `this` passed implicitly as shown is not the same as it would have been for a B object, how does the mechanism work?

Comment: @ustulation: No, the `this` is of the type `B` and the method `B::disp()` is the one getting called, naturally it has access to `x` which is it's own member. There is no slicing here.

Comment: The real rule is _In C++, dynamic dispatch is only used for virtual members_.  Your rule follows from this, and the fact that the language doesn't allow defining variables as virtual.

Comment: @ustulation With regard to slicing: `this` is a pointer, not a class type, so it cannot be sliced.  And `this` only exists within a non-static member function.  Until the function is actually called, the only pointer you have is `aptr`.  Name lookup, overload resolution, access control, etc. all take place using `aptr`, and its (static) type.  Only once the function has been chosen does the compiler consider virtual, and go through the necessary steps to resolve to the dynamic type and create a `this` pointer.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yes, My rule is a combined simplified version, I did combine the two together because it simplify's the detail & it holds good in all possible scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

You are confused, and it seems to me that you come from more dynamic languages.

In C++, compilation and runtime are clearly isolated. A program must first be compiled and then can be run (and any of those steps may fail).

---

So, going backward:

`<2>` fails at compilation, because compilation is about **static** information. `aptr` is of type `A*`, thus all methods and attributes of `A` are accessible through this pointer. Since you declared `disp()` but no `x`, then the call to `disp()` compiles but there is no `x`.

Therefore, `<2>`'s failure is about semantics, and those are defined in the C++ Standard.

---

Getting to `<1>`, it works because there is a *declaration* of `disp()` in `A`. This guarantees the existence of the function (I would remark that you actually lie here, because you did not *defined* it in `A`).

What happens at runtime is semantically defined by the C++ Standard, but the Standard provides no implementation guidance. Most (if not all) C++ compilers will use a virtual table per class + virtual pointer per instance strategy, and your description looks correct in this case.

However this is pure runtime implementation, and the fact that it runs does not retroactively impact the fact that the program compiled.

Answer (score 0):

```
virtual void disp(); //not necessary to define as placeholder in vtable entry will be
                     //overwritten when derived class's vtable entry is prepared after
                     //invoking Base ctor (unless we do new A instead of new B in main() below)
```

Your comment is not strictly correct. A virtual function is *odr-used* unless it is pure (the converse does not necessarily hold) which means that you must provide a definition for it. If you don't want to provide a definition for it you must make it a pure virtual function.

If you make one of these modifications then `aptr->disp();` works and calls the derived class `disp()` because `disp()` in the derived class *overrides* the base class function. The base class function still has to exist as you are calling it through a pointer to base. `x` is not a member of the base class so `aptr->x` is not a valid expression.

Comment: `which means that you must provide a definition for it. If you don't want to provide a definition for it you must make it a pure virtual function.` pls try it out. It works without definition of A::disp()

Comment: @ustulation: Just because it works for you doesn't necessarily mean that your code is correct. Appearing to work is one of the possible behaviours for code with _undefined behavior_.

Comment: @ustulation As Charles Bailey has said, it is undefined behavior.  Whether it works will depend on the compiler, and probably on what the constructor and the destructor of the base class do, and whether they are visible.

Comment: @CharlesBailey : ok! it never struck me it's undefined. since the behavior matched with the explanation i had in mind (the one which i'v written as a comment in the snippet above) i thought there's nothing wrong with not defining it.